# How to Automate The Data-Entry Process of verifying Excel spreadsheet data with web research

Tags: excel, vba, web-applications, automation, data-entry

I have a huge spreadsheet (about 150K rows) with data on businesses. The info is laid out with varying info on each business in columns. Example: business name, website, phone number, email, social media handles, address, latitude, longitude, etc.

I obtained this info over time via individual, team and web-scraped data entry. Not every business has each category of information present. Now I need to verify each cell in each row to ensure accuracy and fill in any missing info if possible. Here's an example:

[spredsheet snippet pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20nGN.png)

In other words, I need to execute the simple, painstaking task of checking google to see: does this business exist/is it still in operation? Of the information I have, how much of it is correct, and what is inaccurate? From the information I am missing, is it available somewhere online? For EACH BUSINESS! :-(

I need to find a way to automate all of the above. Paying someone to "clean" 150K rows of data or doing it manually is out of the question. And I haven't been able to find any VBA or formula solution.

Please tell me the technology exists to solve this problem and that someone can point me to it!

Comment: Without showing what you've done, it would be difficult to assist you with your work. Otherwise, it would be unpaid work that you are looking for. In your words, that would be out of the question.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty huge task - have you considered using commercial sources of this type of data?  They must exist....

Comment: @Mech I just edited my question to include a snippet from the spreadsheet. Not looking for freebies, just sound advice, or some expert to invite me to fiverr/upwork etc so I can get this done if I personally cannot

Comment: @TimWilliams my spreadsheet is a compilation of individuals and group input over the years and some web-scraping. In other words, not all of the data corresponds to a nice, clean commercial source url where I can ID. Some of the businesses might no longer be in business, or I might have bad info or am simply missing info that does exist somewhere online

Comment: @Mech I need another up vote to chat in the room! Lol

Comment: @Mech I just tried to post another question, but the site says I must wait 90 mins! :'(. Might just have to check back in with this tomorrow!

Comment: This could be programmed, but it would be a specific programme designed for this work. It's a huge job as I assume data is missing in any column, apart from business name.

Comment: @Michelle correct. I figured some manner of programming would do the trick. I just need to know what type. The toughest part of this task is not knowing what to ask for at all, in regards to the tools to do the job. Any guesses to the language needed? I've heard python and javascript might be appropriate

Comment: @tawconsu I've got something in the works that would help fill in the missing data.